# couldnot connect azuure notification nhub after some time use

Tags: android, azure, azure-notificationhub

Could not HEAD 'https://dl.bintray.com/microsoftazuremobile/SDK/com/microsoft/azure/azure-notifications-handler/3.5.1/azure-notifications-handler-3.5.1.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the Notification Hub tier you’re leveraging, there are some quota restrictions applied.

I have seen similar issues and the **403 forbidden** typically appears for Create/Update operations when the quota is exceeded, take a look at the [Notificaiton Hub quota pricing page](https://azure.microsoft.com/pricing/details/notification-hubs/) for tier and quota limits for the features.

Example- Active devices per namespace on **Free tier is 500**. If you exceed that limit you may receive such error messages.

Kindly see if this is the case. To test, you may upgrade to Basic or Standard as per your needs and then test it out.

If the issue still persist, you may take a fiddler/network trace to fetch more details on the error.

Also, checkout the **Azure diagnostic blade** to fetch more info. To do this, navigate to your **Azure Notification Hub** in the **Azure portal** and select Diagnose and solve problems to open the diagnostics (as highlighted in the screenshot below).

**Note:** Kindly do not share any PII data on the public forum.

[image]

If the issue still persists, kindly do provide more details about your scenario/requirement.